# Python - excel - count number of words in cell, using two csv dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a Python code which counted occurrences of words on text (.txt) files:

```
find_words = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=[^\w./-])|(?<=^))[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\W|$)').findall
wanted1 = set(find_words(open('word_list_1.csv').read().lower()))
wanted2 = set(find_words(open('word_list_2.csv').read().lower()))
negators = set(find_words(open('negators.csv').read().lower()))
ignore = set(find_words(open('Ignore words.csv').read().lower()))
```

then I would do the following to process the text files:

```
with open(csvfile, "wb") as output:
 writer = csv.writer(output)
 for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
            print "Processing file number : ", i, " out of :", len(glob.glob("*.txt"))
            i=i+1
            with open(f) as inputfile:
                wordNumber=0
                for line in inputfile:
                 if find_words(line.lower()) != []:
                    lineWords=find_words(line.lower())
```

So, the question is, how do I do that for an excel file instead of .txt files? I tried to do the following:

```
for i in range(0, rows):
  for j in range(0,cols):
    write_sheet1.write(i,j,sheet.cell_value(i,j))
  if sheet.cell_value(i,4)!=0:
    for line in sheet.cell_value(i,4):
 print "Line is : ", line
 if find_words(line.lower()) != []:
    lineWords=find_words(line.lower())
```

but it is not working, it returns only one character, not the whole line and/or words...

So how can I make it work for excel cells instead of text files?

Comment: What is the type of `sheet.cell_value(i,4)`? If it is a string, you may want to `.split('\n')` first.

Comment: it is a string usually. I don't care if I examine it line by line, as long as I check if every word is in the word list, et cetera. Can you give me a specific example of what you mean?

Comment: Your `for line in sheet.cell_value(i,4):` is not needed for a cell because the cell value is a single string rather than a list of lines. Try checking `find_words(sheet.cell_value(i, 4).lower())` directly.

Comment: Hi @Stuart, I think what you say makes sense. I tried it and it seems to be working. Please post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a text file Python lets you iterate over it as if it were a list of lines. By contrast the value of a spreadsheet cell is (presumably) just a string, so you can directly find the words in it.

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        write_sheet1.write(i, j, sheet.cell_value(i, j))
        if find_words(sheet.cell_value(i, 4)) != []:
            cell_words = find_words(sheet.cell_value(i, 4).lower())
```

If the cell may contain something other than a string (such as a number) then you will need to convert it to a string first using `str()`. (I'm not sure what module you are using to read the Excel sheets.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use pandas to import the Excel file, then iterate over all cells in the pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(...)
df_out = df.applymap(func)
```

where func is the function that takes the content of the cell and returns your result. The result for each cell will be in df_out.

Comment: Hello, please give a prover example, related to my example, I cannot understand what you're saying